# installLibrary, move all functions to the global namespace

Tags: javascript

I am writing a library, and I have all functions being called with "lib.someFunction();" or "lib.someVariable;". I know I shouldn't pollute the global namespace, but I want to give users of my library that option. I heard some libraries have an "option" like "installLibrary();" that moves all functions and variables in a class to the global namespace.

This way, only users would prefer so would be able to call "someVariable;" or "someFunction();" directly.

My problem, though, is how to write such a function. Any ideas?

Comment: Browser or Node.js?  Also, don't do that.

Comment: It's probably not hard.  How is your code structured?

Comment: Browser. I have a `function Library() { this.var = 5; this.otherVar = 4; this.cool = function() { } }
var library = new Library();`.

And then I call functions and vars like this: `library.cool();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
function Library() { 
    this.var = 5; 
    this.otherVar = 4; 
    this.cool = function(x) {
        return x + this.otherVar;
    }
} 
var library = new Library();

(function (lib, context) {
    for (var prop in lib) {
        if (lib.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop) {
            if (typeof lib[prop] == "function") {
                context[prop] = function() {
                    return lib[prop].apply(lib, arguments);
                }
            } else {
               context[prop] = lib[prop]; 
            }
        }
    }
}(library, this));
```

But beware of using anything other than functions here.  If you do this and try to adjust parameters on the global/window namespace, they will not get carried back to your library functions and might not get the behavior you want.  For example:

```
library.cool(3);  // 7
cool(3);          // 7
otherVar = 10;
library.cool(3);  // 7
cool(3);          // 7  Still?
library.otherVar = 10;
library.cool(3);  // 13
cool(3);          // 13  Finally!
```

An alternative which doesn't have this restriction would be to apply your library constructor function to the global/window object:

```
Library.call(this);
```

The trouble with that is that you don't just pollute the global scope with your public API but also with anything that you might have stored in your local closure along the way.  That strikes me as way too heavy.

If your library uses something like the revealing module pattern and exposes only functions, then I think the first is pretty straightforward.  But as others have said, it may not be wise.  At the very most, I would offer this as an option for users but warn against it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious reasons for not polluting the global space with your library, I believe that you could do something like the following.

**Note:** I've written this to look to see if we are within the browser or node. You should be able to reference "window" in the browser and "global" in node for the global namespace.

```
var scope = (typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : global);
scope.someVariable = true;
scope.someFunction = function() { };

// Essentially, this is the same as:
window.someFunction = function() { };
// or
global.someFunction = function() { };
```